# Looping through two columns, storing the value if a certain conditoin is met

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I'm very amateur at vba but I have two columns of data Column 1 and Column 2 - both of varying lengths

This should be able to be done in a nested for loop with an if statement.

---- sorry here is an image that will help with waht I'm trying to say ---
So I want compare each value in column 2 to column 1, if the difference of the two divided by the original is <0.01 I want to store the Description next to column 2 so "apple" into the details of Column 1.

if it doesn't fit that match then try the second value in column 1, if a fit is found the column 2 value is done, now go to the next  value. Repeat recycle

I hope this is a better explanation.

Image of problem:

[image]

Comment: My VBA is a bit rusty, but... Do 2 foreach loops. Foreach and then set a dim to the 2nd column (or increase an index and do arr[index] then do another foreach within that foreach on the same array but selecting the first column. Set the first column to another variable within the second foreach, then do a compare statement.

Comment: This would be easier to answer if we had sample data and expected result. Also, "...smaller than one hundredths" can be interpreted is more than one way (smaller than `0.01` or smaller than `1/100th` of the values being compared?). Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54207349/edit) to provide some more info? WHat you've tried so far would also be useful

Comment: It sounds like a formula would be easier and more efficient way of doing this. Just put it in the third column.  If A1=B1 then "YEAH", else "AH man!"

Comment: What does "error between the two" mean? Please share sample data and expected outcomes from that sample data. It's not clear what you are doing here.

Comment: Okay, I've added an image of an example data set and clarified what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an array formula you can do something like this:

[image]

Here's how the formula evaluates step-by-step (selecting parts of the formula and then hitting F9 to evaluate the selected part and replace with the result:

[image]

Multiplying the array of TRUE/FALSE coerces it to an array of 1/0, and that's what we feed to MATCH(), looking for the first 1.

Comment: Thank you Tim this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Do you mind explanining to me why it needs to be in array nomenclature? And when I tried using index match before I think it was not allowing the values to be stored because there was no exact match yet you have gotten around that here.